# Sentry Please check if your DSN is set properly in your config or .env as `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN`

Tags: php, laravel, exception, sentry

I've installed Sentry on my Laravel project, but I can't run it. Whenever I run command `php artisan sentry:test`, the result is:

```
[Sentry] DSN discovered!
[Sentry] Generating test Event
[Sentry] Sending test Event
[Sentry] There was an error sending the test event.
[Sentry] Please check if your DSN is set properly in your config or `.env` as `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN`.
```

but I've added the DSN in my .env file.

Comment: As the previous output suggests, the DSN was discovered and everything but there was an error sending the test event. This means the DSN is invalid/broken or it can't reach the Sentry instance the DSN points to. Are you using sentry.io or a self-hosted instance? And are you on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to put the DSN in the .env file like this

```
SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=https://34412344274048ccbfasfdgdffaf7f38d47c@o111111111.ingest.sentry.io/222334456
```

and don't forget to cache the config

```
PHP artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You find your DSN in your Sentry account under "Client Keys" in your project settings.

When you have located the DSN copy it and add it to your `.env` file like this:

`SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=YOUR_SENTRY_DSN_HERE`

To handle unhandled errors you also need to put this in your `App/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
            app('sentry')->captureException($e);
        }
    });
}
```

You probably already have a `register` method there. If it empty you should replace it with this. If you have something there you probably have to merge this `register` with your current one. If you want help with that, post your current `register` method here.

After this `php artisan sentry:test` should work. You might have to clear the cache if you have config cache turned on in your environment (`php artisan config:clear`). After you have verified that is works you should probably remove the DSN from you `.env` in your local environment and add it to your production and staging environments if you have any.

Here is a link to the Sentry documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/

I would also recommend that you enable performance monitoring. It is a great feature!